# Laravel Livewire Star Rating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have need to complete the functionality of rating start. In this code two Models use Post model and PostRate models.
Post Model have three attributes like id, title, description
PostRate have id, post_id, rate.
I have make livewire Component **Rate** and Resource of **rate**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\PostRate;
use Livewire\Component;

class Rate extends Component
{
    public $currentRating=false;
    public $postId;
    
    public function render()
    {
        $post = Post::withCount('rates')->latest('id')->first();
        $this->postId = $post->id;
        return view('livewire.rate', compact('post'));
    }

    public function rate($rating)
    {
        PostRate::create(['post_id'=>$this->postId,'rate'=>$rating]);
        $this->currentRating = true;

    }

}
```

**Resource Rate**

```
<div>
    <h2 class="text-3xl">{{ $post->title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ $post->description }}</p>
    <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
        Current rating: <b>2.83 / 5 ({{ $post->rates_count }} votes)</b>
    </div>
    <h3 class="text-2xl">Rate the post</h3>

    <div class="flex">
        <img src="http://demo-star-rating.livewirekit.com/img/star-active.png" width="30">

        <a wire:click.prevent="rate(1)" href="#"><img src="http://demo-star-rating.livewirekit.com/img/star-inactive.png" width="30"></a>
        <a wire:click.prevent="rate(2)" href="#"><img src="http://demo-star-rating.livewirekit.com/img/star-inactive.png" width="30"></a>
        <a wire:click.prevent="rate(3)" href="#"><img src="http://demo-star-rating.livewirekit.com/img/star-inactive.png" width="30"></a>
        <a wire:click.prevent="rate(4)" href="#"><img src="http://demo-star-rating.livewirekit.com/img/star-inactive.png" width="30"></a>
        <a wire:click.prevent="rate(5)" href="#"><img src="http://demo-star-rating.livewirekit.com/img/star-inactive.png" width="30"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        You rated: 4 / 5
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and the question is...

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you handle the relationship between Post and Rate and could be many to many and be sure if your function will accept more than one vote for the same user. Maybe if you explain more about your task